# Python import warning

Tags: python

Let's say I want to use scipy in my program, giving it the alias sp. I also want to use the linalg module from scipy. Unlike what happens with numpy, the module is not automatically imported. So I have to write:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.linalg
```

This achieves the desired result: I can now write `sp.linalg.inv(...)`.

The problem is that the line `import scipy.linalg` also imports scipy. And given that all my calls to scipy are made using the alias sp, **spyder** gives me the warning *'scipy' imported but unused* in the second line.

What would be the right way of doing this? Or is mine the right way and the problem is just spyder's?

I could do:

```
import scipy.linalg
sp = scipy
```

But that doesn't look really pythonic..

Comment: Using scipy version 0.14.0, when I `import scipy as sp`, I *automatically* have access to `sp.linalg`.

Comment: @ArtOfWare: no, it is "special to the module". `import scipy as sp` does not give you access to `sp.stats` for example.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare it _is_ special to the module as submodules will only get loaded if they're explicitly imported in `__init__.py` (or, of course, in a submodule), and are only visible if there's no `__all__` saying otherwise. You can trivially check this by creating two empty, nested packages; by simply importing the outer package you won't be able to access the child module.

Comment: I think Spyder is overzealous here; I've seen similar things with pylint. I would ignore it (and perhaps bring it up on a Spyder mailing/issue tracker).

Comment: @l4mpi: Okay. I retract my comments and answer, then.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Shame, you should've asked for a few more downvotes and only then remove your answer, just to get [the badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure).

Comment: @Evert: I'm here to help, not collect badges/rep. If my answer was doing the opposite of helping, then it needed to be removed. Although it would be nice if I got enough rep to mark questions protected myself so I wouldn't need to flag them for a moderator to protect them for me...

Comment: It may be that Spyder is overzealous.. But still, it looks kind of redundant. If the line `import scipy.linalg` already imports scipy, is it really ok to have another line also importing it, just to give it an alias?

Comment: @LGenzelis: Yes, it is "okay", in so far as it achieves the purpose of defining `sp`. And it is not inefficient, since modules are cached in `sys.modules`, so importing scipy a second time is merely a dict lookup. Perhaps you don't *need* `sp` however. `linalg` is shorter to write than `sp.linalg`, and just as explicit. Thus, `from scipy import linalg, stats, ...`  could suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
from scipy import linalg
```

then `scipy` will not be added to the global namespace, though this will add `linalg` to the global namespace.

---

As a technical note, it *is* possible to define `sp.linspace` without adding `scipy` or `linspace` to globals:

```
import importlib
import scipy as sp
sp.linalg = importlib.import_module('scipy.linalg')
```

Note only `sp` is in `globals()`:

```
print(globals().keys())
# ['__builtins__', '__file__', 'sp', '__package__', '__name__', '__doc__']
```

Or, alternatively,

```
import scipy as sp
sp.linalg = __import__('scipy.linalg', fromlist=['linalg'])
```

Comment: Would it be so bad to add the 10 words of explanation _before_ clicking submit? Seriously, why do people post incomplete answers and then immediately edit them? You can't even get an "enlightened" badge as you're already not the first to answer...

Comment: But then `linalg` will be added to the global namespace, so you have the same issue in a different way.

Comment: This would be a posible solution.. This lets me use `sp.linalg.some_function(...)` ... But it also adds `linalg` to the global namespace, and I don't want that.

Comment: Why do people so often stick in random IPy prompts in their answer?